# Laravel - periodically pulling from a database table

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, I have a table of articles which I pulled from a database at the start of my project over a month ago.

This database is separate from my Laravel application but the content may change daily and I've been manually grabbing the content every three days, which as you can imagine takes time.

I've seen that you can have two database connects in Laravel, like so:

```
<?php
return array(

'default' => 'mysql',

'connections' => array(

    # Our primary database connection
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host1',
        'database'  => 'database1',
        'username'  => 'user1',
        'password'  => 'pass1'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    # Our secondary database connection
    'mysql2' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host2',
        'database'  => 'database2',
        'username'  => 'user2',
        'password'  => 'pass2'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
),
```

);

So, If I have my secondary article table that I can connect to is it possible to create a cron job that pulls in new content to my Laravel application every hour?

When pulling from the secondary database, how could I avoid overwriting content?

Comment: I'll clear up the question.

Comment: Are the (relevant) tables in the other database the same as the ones in your app i.e. columns? Are the ids the same in the other app or are they 2 datasets that you're merging together effectively?

Comment: They should be completely in sync but the fields may have different names...

Comment: "is it possible to create a cron job" - yes, "When pulling from the secondary database, how could I avoid overwriting content?" - selecting data does not cause any data to be written let alone overwritten.

Comment: I meant more can you grab data and add it to another table.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a model for the secondary database like this

```
namespace App\Secondary;

class Article extends Model {

    protected $connection = 'mysql2';

    public static function fetchArticles(){
      //fetch articles

      //TODO all other filter to fetch new records
      $articles = Article::all();
       return $articles;
    }
}
```

> How to avoid overwrite content?

if you have id or any identity column in both primary and secondary connection db table then just fetch the latest article id from primary connection article table and fetch new articles after that id from secondary db table.

> Here is the scheduler class

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ArticlePuller extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'articlePuller';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Pull article from secondary database';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $articles = Secondary/Article::fetchArticles(); //from secondary db table 
        Article::insertArticles($articles); 
    }
}
```

> Define this scheduler in console/Kernel.php

```
 protected $commands = [
    Commands\ArticlePuller::class
 ];

 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
 {
    $schedule->command('articlePuller')->hourly();
 }
```

> Now need to add this scheduler entry in cron job

```
* * * * * php path_to_artisan/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Just to confirm, in fetchArticles would I just grab the data from each field?

Comment: you will fetch all the new records(with the column that you need) that you want to insert in primary connection db table.

Comment: So, would it be as simple as as $title->title

Comment: yes, i have updated my answer check it. Both model has same name `Article` only difference is `namespace`. Now both model is Laravel model fetch it same as you do in your primary connection

Comment: did you try it ?